# can I bind mutiple form inputs to one property of a bean?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement using springs similar to the example shown here '

Model Object

```
class Bean{

private String names;

//Getters & Setters

}
```

### JSP form

```
<form:input path ="name">
<form:input path="name">
```

can i  bind all the "name" inputs to the one bean property "names" using any delimiter?

Comment: Are you using two input binded to the same property inside the same form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple form elements with a single name are combined into a list/array. This can be retrieved via [`request.getParamaterValues`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29)

The web framework you use should wrap it and populate `List` in your bean.

For instance with Struts2, if you have multiple elements with name `name`, declare a `List<String>` in the bean with setters (and getters) and Struts2 will populate the list with the values.

```
class Bean {
    private List<String> names;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used List for check boxes but I forgot that the same applies to even text boxes lol..